# Trouble with building 'rviz' in hydro [Possible cause shiboken]

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-hydro, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I am new to ROS community and currently building hydro from source on ubuntu 12.04. I have been following the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source) and am having trouble with building rviz package. I am on this step:

```
user@ubuntu12.04:~/ros_catkin_ws/$./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

Until now, my errors were mainly due to the absence of some C++ header files, but in this case, I am not sure what the error is. Here is my log:

```
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.3")
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Python version: 2.7
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/ros/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rviz/test_results
-- Found gtest: gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.90
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
making version 1.10.19.
-- checking for module 'assimp'
--   found assimp, version 2.0
-- Assimp version does not have unified headers
-- checking for module 'yaml-cpp>=0.5'
--   package 'yaml-cpp>=0.5' not found
TODO: convert rviz tests to catkin.
-- libshiboken built for Release
Using SHIBOKEN_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libshiboken-python2.7.so
-- Using default python: -python2.7
Using PYSIDE_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpyside-python2.7.so
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so (Required is at least version "2.7")
-- Shiboken binding generator available.
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found suitable version "2.7.3", required is "2.7")
-- SIP binding generator available.
Python binding generators: shiboken;sip
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
user@ubuntu12.04:~/ros_catkin_ws/$
```

I tried [removing the shiboken](https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/issues/35#issuecomment-28527836) as suggested, but then it showed an error of "Shiboken binding generator NOT available." Can anyone point out what I am missing? Or just point me to the right page? Tell me if you require some other info:)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206572/trouble-with-building-%27rviz%27-in-hydro-%5Bpossible-cause-shiboken%5D/) by [adi93](https://answers.ros.org/users/22074/adi93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This doesn't look like a problem with shiboken.

It looks like it's failing to find yaml-cpp:

```
--   package 'yaml-cpp>=0.5' not found
```

Have you tried using rosdep to install the required dependencies?

```
rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1